# Can I Import Results From Excel Into Test Rail?

Tags: excel, testing, import, testrail, excel-import

We have just started using Test Rail in our business. One of our user testers has extracted their Test Run into Excel and has completed all of their testing within the Excel document (don't ask I don't know why).

Is there a way - for a relatively non-technical guy like me - to import these results back into the Test Run? The only import options I can see are for the Test Cases themselves not the results from a Test Run.

Appreciate any help that can be given I tried searching for this on google and here but came up short.

Best regards
Andy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.